C# markup Maui Can't bind properties
I can't figure out how to create a custom ItemTemplate for a Shell object
AppShell.xaml.cs
using AppStockAndOrdersMAUI.Views.Orders;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup;

namespace AppStockAndOrdersMAUI;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {        
        Items.Add(new ShellContent()
        {
            Title = "Home",
            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MainPage()),
            Route = nameof(MainPage)
        });
        
        Items.Add(new ShellContent()
        {
            Title = "Orders",
            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new OrdersListPage()),
            Route = nameof(OrdersListPage)
        });

        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new Label().Bind(Label.TextProperty, "Title"));
        
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(OrdersListPage), typeof(OrdersListPage));
    }
}

AppShell.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="AppStockAndOrdersMAUI.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppStockAndOrdersMAUI"
    Title="AppStockAndOrdersMAUI">
        
    
</Shell>

I've also tried
ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new Label().Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(ShellContent.Title)));

Items are no longer displayed in the menu


try using hardcoded text in the label instead of binding.  This will tell you if the problem is in the template or the data source

@Jason Still nothing shows up in the menu

Where are you setting ItemsSource?

You can recheck if you have set property  Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout" for file AppShell.xaml?

@Jason in the constructor AppShell

@JessieZhang-MSFT I don't call the method InitializeComponent() I'm trying to describe everything in c#

the code you posted doesn't show that

Hi @WebMorda, could you please post the full code of AppShell.xaml and AppShell.xaml.cs so that we can help you better?

@JessieZhang-MSFT Published the full code of the files

Got the problem solved, added Grid, now everything displays as it should
using AppStockAndOrdersMAUI.Views.Orders;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup;

namespace AppStockAndOrdersMAUI;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {        
        Items.Add(new ShellContent()
        {
            Title = "Home",
            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MainPage()),
            Route = nameof(MainPage)
        });
        
        Items.Add(new ShellContent()
        {
            Title = "Orders",
            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new OrdersListPage()),
            Route = nameof(OrdersListPage)
        });

        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => 
        
            new Grid
            {
                Padding = 10,
                Children =
                {
                    new Label().Bind(Label.TextProperty, "Title").FontSize(20)
                        .TextColor(Color.FromHex("#00A1B1"))
                        .CenterVertical()
                        .Start()
                }
            });
        
        
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(OrdersListPage), typeof(OrdersListPage));
    }

